# Flutter - Routing between different Views

Tags: view, routes, dart, flutter

So, I have this file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "calculateDerivations.dart";
import "calculateRoots.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Ableitungen berechnen'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text(config.title)),
      body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          new InputWidget(),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  InputWidgetState createState() => new InputWidgetState();
}

class InputWidgetState extends State<InputWidget> {

  InputValue val = new InputValue(text: "");
  String ersteAbleitung = "";
  String zweiteAbleitung = "";
  String dritteAbleitung = "";
  String roots = "";
  String function = "";

  void _submitted(){
    setState((){
      /*
       * Redirect here
       */
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Column(
        children: [
          new Input(
            value: val,
            labelText: 'Funktion hier eingeben',
            onChanged: (InputValue newInputValue) {
              setState(() {
                val = newInputValue;
              });
          }),
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: _submitted,
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

As soon as the user now clicks the IconButton (which calls _submitted), I want him to be redirected to a new View (Widget). How would I solve this routing problem in Flutter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normal route navigation might look like this:

```
new IconButton(
    icon: new Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => new MyCustomView(),
        );
    )
)
```

You can also use named routes by passing a map of `WidgetBuilder`s as the `routes` constructor argument for your `MaterialApp`, or by passing an `onGenerateRoute` handler. There's an [example](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/221023a99dc7d4e1a6b1bd3d53e5d9551b785774/lib/demos/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_bar_demo.dart#L19) of named routes in the Flutter gallery.

If you don't want there to be an animation, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation/43685697).

Comment: Thanks, will try it our soon!

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there a way to change the duration and direction of the animation?

Comment: Yes. Follow the example I gave in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation/43685697).

You can customize the duration with this code:
    @override Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 100);

Comment: In the common case where you want it to slide in from the bottom, use the "fullscreenDialog: true" argument to MaterialPageRoute. 

To slide from other directions, use a customized MaterialPageRoute with SlideTransition. See [MaterialPageRoute](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Got everything working how I wanted it to :)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: I fixed the link to the example