# How to add custom transitions to my Flutter route in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, transition

How can I add custom transitions to my Flutter route? This is my current route structure.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Yaip',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
                brightness: Brightness.light
            ),
            home: new VerifyPhoneNumber(),
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                '/verified': (BuildContext context) =>  new MobileNumberVerified(),
                '/setupprofile': (BuildContext context) =>  new SetUpProfile()
            },
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `PageRouteBuilder`:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 15):

You can change the transition theme of the MaterialApp widget to use the CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder if you want iOS like animations for all your routes

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData(
   pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
   TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
   TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
   }),
...
)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can subclass [`MaterialPageRoute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html) and override [`buildTransitions`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute/buildTransitions.html). Check out [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation/43685697#43685697) for example code.

Comment: would be very grateful if you could throw in an example with this structure for me. and how do make in such a way that i can use my  vary the transitions depending on my requirement in the same app

Comment: I edited my answer to link to one of my previous Stack Overflow answers that has example code.

Comment: can I set a different transition for entering and leaving( that's page enter transitions and page leave transitions), and how do I make transition duration fast?

Comment: Why not just given extra parameter to do animation for named route would be beneficial to developers

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if you wish to use other packages than default material one then there is one beautiful library/package available in flutter known as "Fluro".
You can use this library with less overhead.
here is the link to official fluro - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluro
 you can learn this completely from the provided example directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PageRouteBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageRouteBuilder-class.html) for a custom page transition. You can achieve various types of page transition effects. Below are some commented custom page transition you can uncomment one of them and run to see how it works on different transitions.

```
PageRouteBuilder _pageRouteBuilder() {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
        return Demo2();
      },
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        // return SlideTransition(
        //   position: animation.drive(
        //     Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(-1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero),
        //   ),
        //   child: SlideTransition(
        //     position: Tween<Offset>(
        //       begin: Offset.zero,
        //       end: Offset(0.0, 1.0),
        //     ).animate(secondaryAnimation),
        //     child: child,
        //   ),
        // );
        // return ScaleTransition(
        //   scale: animation.drive(
        //     Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).chain(
        //       CurveTween(
        //         curve: Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.elasticIn),
        //       ),
        //     ),
        //   ),
        //   child: ScaleTransition(
        //     scale: Tween<double>(begin: 1.5, end: 1.0).animate(
        //       CurvedAnimation(
        //         parent: animation,
        //         curve: Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.elasticInOut),
        //       ),
        //     ),
        //     child: child,
        //   ),
        // );
        return ScaleTransition(
          scale: CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.elasticInOut),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
  }
```

And now suppose I have to open a new route on a click of a button:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, _pageRouteBuilder());
            },
            child: Text('Go!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to create a RouteGenerator class with string values for named routes.  This way you reference all your routes from one class.  The RouteGenerator class contains one method:  static Route handleRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) with case statements for each MaterialPageRoute.

A switch statement matches the string to a route and the MaterialPageRoute pushes the widget on the stack.  you can also get access to arguments passed to the Route Generator

in main.dart

```
  onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.handleRoute,
```

navigation from a childwidget

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteGenerator.page1Page,
                                arguments: myCustomView)
```

Class

```
 class RouteGenerator {
  static const String homePage = "/home";
  static const String page1Page = "/page1";
  static const String page2Page = "/page2";

  RouteGenerator._();
  static Route<dynamic> handleRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
   Widget childWidget;
   switch (routeSettings.name) {
    case homePage:
    {
      childWidget = HomePageWidget(title: 'Performance Reviews');
    }
    break;
  case page1Page:
    {
      childWidget = Page1Widget();
    }
    break;
  case page2Page:
    {
      final args = routeSettings.arguments as MyCustomView;
      childWidget = Page2Widget(args);
    }
    break;
  default:
    throw FormatException("Route Not Found");
  }
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => childWidget);
 }
 }
```