# How to navigate to other page without animation Flutter

Tags: navigation, flutter

I have a Login page, when I log on to go to the main page of my app i am using
`Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new Page1()));`
But it have the slide animation, i want to disable it.

this is my Material app format

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Login(title: 'Login'),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/screen3': (BuildContext context) => new Page1(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to change the content of the page without a new page/route

Comment: It could work, but i was meaning navigate to a page cleaning the stack without the animation of the navigation.

Comment: You can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation

Answer (score 131):

You can use `PageRouteBuilder`.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context, 
    PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => Page1(),
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
    ),
);
```

Comment: add transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0), to make transition instantly.

Comment: add `reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero` for no delayed pop!

Answer (score 39):

You would need to override the `buildTransitions`  method to prevent animations.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute({
    required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings? settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  }) : super(
            builder: builder,
            maintainState: maintainState,
            settings: settings,
            fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any way to determine whether the animation is for opening or closing? I'd like to keep the animation for closing.

Comment: @Janneman I don't know, but you can try to keep animation or secondaryAnimation.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b31ca1aaca0b9ef70ec478a74b3b690e4d632616/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart line 105

Comment: Amazing stuff!!

Comment: why not just https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774013/5060513? can you explain the plus and drawbacks?

Answer (score 22):

You can override `MaterialPageRoute` to set `transitionDuration` to zero:

```
class CustomPageRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  CustomPageRoute({builder}) : super(builder: builder);

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 0);
}

...

Navigator.of(context).push(
  CustomPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return DashboardView();
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can this solution be used for pushNamed aswell? If so, how?

Comment: for pushNamed use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774013/119861

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you also set `transitionDuration` otherwise you may push the new route without animation but when you press back button, you'll see some delay.

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Screen2(),
    transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
  ),
);
```

Comment: that is correct with duration to zero seconds method we get delay on closing route. and that is very annoying look like a lug.

Comment: And there's `reverseTransitionDuration`, which you can set to `0` also.

Answer (score 9):

### EDIT: This simple solution longer works. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51649 .

Good luck using the Navigator 2.0 API.

---

My solution is to define the route with `isInitialRoute:true`.  This prevents Flutter from showing an animation when the route is pushed.

Here's a working example and screen recording:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart'
    show
        CupertinoApp,
        CupertinoButton,
        CupertinoPageRoute,
        CupertinoPageScaffold;
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'
    show
        BuildContext,
        Center,
        Column,
        Navigator,
        Route,
        RouteSettings,
        SafeArea,
        Spacer,
        Text,
        runApp,
        Widget;

Widget makeButton(BuildContext context, String routeName) =>
    new CupertinoButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, routeName),
      child: Text('Go to \'$routeName\''),
    );

Route generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case 'not-animated':
      return new CupertinoPageRoute(
        settings: RouteSettings(name: settings.name, isInitialRoute: true),
        builder: (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Spacer(),
                      Text('This is \'not-animated\''),
                      makeButton(context, 'animated'),
                      Spacer(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    CupertinoApp(
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      initialRoute: 'animated',
      routes: {
        'animated': (context) => CupertinoPageScaffold(
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Spacer(),
                      Text('This is \'animated\''),
                      makeButton(context, 'not-animated'),
                      Spacer(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: screen recording]

Comment: The simplest way to achieve a simple result: navigate without animations. Thanks!

Comment: I think this solution does not work on pop or popUntil?

Comment: Outstanding and simple, thanks a lot! It works perfectly in Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8.

Comment: isInitialRoute has been removed (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51649)

Comment: `isInitialRoute` is no longer there. Please remove this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a note at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In case you would like to use a package, with the [get package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) you can disable transition animations with a property of `GetMaterialApp`.

```
GetMaterialApp(
  defaultTransition: Transition.noTransition, //this would be the solution
  transitionDuration: transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
);
```

And then just simply add the other desired properties.

Answer (score 5):

You should try to extend MaterialPageRoute and override buildTransitions as follows:

```
class ExPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {

 @override
 Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return child;
 }
}
```

Comment: The `builder` goes missing.

Answer (score 2):

With Navigator 2.0, there are two ways:

1. Rebuild the Navigator with a new `pages` list that has the last item replaced. If the previous `Page` and replacement `Page` both have no key or the same key, then Flutter will treat them as the same page and will not animate.
2. Set [`Navigator.transitionDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/transitionDelegate.html) to an object that extends [`TransitionDelegate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionDelegate/resolve.html).  The delegate must check for a new record with [`RouteTransitionRecord.isWaitingForEnteringDecision`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteTransitionRecord/isWaitingForEnteringDecision.html) true and call its [`markForAdd()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteTransitionRecord/markForAdd.html) method.  There is some useful code in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69315#issuecomment-833212172 .

Answer (score 1):

Example with navigator 2.0 without animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

var userName = '';
var password = '';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Navigator(
        transitionDelegate: NoAnimationTransitionDelegate(),
        pages: [
          MaterialPage(child: HomePage()),
          if (password.isEmpty) MaterialPage(child: PasswordPage()),
          if (userName.isEmpty) MaterialPage(child: UserNamePage()),
        ],
        onPopPage: (route, result) {
          if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
          return true;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
  }
}

class PasswordPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.amber);
  }
}

class UserNamePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.green);
  }
}

class NoAnimationTransitionDelegate extends TransitionDelegate<void> {
  @override
  Iterable<RouteTransitionRecord> resolve({
    required List<RouteTransitionRecord> newPageRouteHistory,
    required Map<RouteTransitionRecord?, RouteTransitionRecord> locationToExitingPageRoute,
    required Map<RouteTransitionRecord?, List<RouteTransitionRecord>> pageRouteToPagelessRoutes,
  }) {
    final results = <RouteTransitionRecord>[];

    for (final pageRoute in newPageRouteHistory) {
      if (pageRoute.isWaitingForEnteringDecision) {
        pageRoute.markForAdd();
      }
      results.add(pageRoute);
    }

    for (final exitingPageRoute in locationToExitingPageRoute.values) {
      if (exitingPageRoute.isWaitingForExitingDecision) {
        exitingPageRoute.markForRemove();
        final pagelessRoutes = pageRouteToPagelessRoutes[exitingPageRoute];
        if (pagelessRoutes != null) {
          for (final pagelessRoute in pagelessRoutes) {
            pagelessRoute.markForRemove();
          }
        }
      }
      results.add(exitingPageRoute);
    }

    return results;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without transitions. Only Fade in next page

```
class FadeInPageRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T> {
  FadeInPageRoute({
    RouteSettings? settings,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(settings: settings);

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => Colors.black;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => '';

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return builder(context);
  }

  @override
  bool canTransitionTo(TransitionRoute<dynamic> nextRoute) {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: animation.value,
      child: builder(context),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 700);
}
```