# Problems with returning to App using two Screens with Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

#### Seems to be a more severe bug with flutte google maps. Is a duplicate of [#25653](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25653)

#### Update 8th August: Current Progress:

Tried to fix the bug with Sukhi, but he wasn't able to reproduce the bug. My colleagues all were able to reproduce it, but wheren't able to fix it :P. Did anyone else manage to reproduce it?

Also created a [github repo with my code](https://github.com/Menelphor/google_maps_bug) and updated the "what I tried so far"

#### Updated on 5th August, getting closer to the real problem

### Explanation of the Problem:

My problem only occurs on **IOs** on **real devices** (not Simulator) on **debug** and **release**.

I do use the google Maps widget with some markers. Tapping on on Marker opens another Screen with more Information, another google Maps widget and the possibility to Navigate via url launcher. (I reduced the Screens to only show the widgets causing the problem)

Leaving the app from this screen (by tapping start navigation for example or going to the IOs homescreen) and then comming back to the app leads to an issue.

If i go back to the App homescreen again, only a white screen is shown.

#### Addition:

Wrapping the Google Maps Widget in the info Screen in a Flex Widget (Column or Row) even leads to a worse behaviour. When returning to the Apps HomeScreen, additional content of the Flex Widget (for example a Container with Text) will stay visible.

#### What I tried so far to get it to work but didn't work:

1. Release Mode => Same Problem
2. Disabled Navigation Transition ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874272/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-without-animation-flutter))
3. async await url launch
4. Building on IOs 12.3 & 12.4
5. Building the Maps Widget inside a Future Builder

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Install [google_maps_flutter 0.5.20+1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) and [url_launcher: 5.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) (I know it is not the latest, but thats not the problem)
2. Copy the CodeSnippet in a flutter project and build on IOs.
3. Tap on the Marker
4. Tap on Button "Start Navigation" or leave the App
5. Tap in Apple Maps on the upper left corner redirecting to the App or reopen the App
6. Your back in the info screen, tap on the left Arrow in the upper left corner
7. Only a white screen is visible

### Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: const LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
          zoom: 7,
        ),
        markers: Set<Marker>()
          ..add(
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('hi'),
              position: LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
              consumeTapEvents: true,
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoScreen()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InfoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("info Page"),),
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: const LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
          zoom: 7,
        ),
        markers: Set<Marker>()
          ..add(
            Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId('hi2'),
              consumeTapEvents: true,
              position: LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
              onTap: () {
                if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  launch('https://maps.apple.com/?q=47.6,8.8796');
                } else {
                  launch(
                      'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.6,8.8796');
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 19, horizontal: 25),
          height: 80,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (Platform.isIOS) {
                launch('https://maps.apple.com/?q=47.6,8.8796');
              } else {
                launch(
                    'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.6,8.8796');
              }
            },
            child: Text(
              'START NAVIGATION',
              style: TextStyle(
                letterSpacing: 0.35,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### flutter doctor:

```
dynClient36:flutter_app mhein$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale de-DE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
dynClient36:flutter_app mhein$
```

```
info plist

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>flutter_app</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>JELEJÖLWEKQÖEwkÖ</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always Permission</string>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on an iPhone 6. When launching through Xcode it actually threw this error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)` in Runner/Runner/Supporting Files/main.m.

After awaiting the url launches in the onTap functions like this:

```
onTap: () async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await launch('https://maps.apple.com/?q=47.6,8.8796');
  } else {
    await launch('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.6,8.8796');
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to reproduce the bug again.
I guess the Flutter Application is not correctly going into background mode when the url launch isn't awaited.

Comment: But that would not explain that the bug also occurs when leaving the App another way. Also it did not work for me :(

Answer (score 4):

Ran your code and solved the issue by adding the following key in the info.plist

Key name : io.flutter.embedded_views_preview
Type : boolean
Value : Yes

When I ran the code on my iPhone 5S, I could see the blank white screen at the beginning (So, not even HomePage() was displayed). There was an error though which was :

```
[VERBOSE-2:platform_view_layer.cc(19)] Trying to embed a platform view but the PrerollContext does not support embedding
```

This leads to the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24434) on Github related to Google Maps plug-in for iOS.

PoC is [here](https://youtu.be/3wTY4ft1gf4) for your reference.

Comment: The Value  <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
 <true/> is already set.. But gonna look if this causes the problem

Comment: Strange it isn't working at your end. With the exact same code, I don't find any issue on my device. Do you get any exception in step 6 or 7 ?

Comment: nope, not a single error thrown.. Even tried to debugg the error and didn't find any problem. (For the debug mode I'm back at the Apps Homescreen working perfectly)

Comment: Oh little addition. It works on the Simulator, but not on real devices and I did test it with 3 diffrent IOs phones.. :(

Comment: Quite strange. I uninstalled the app on my iPhone 5S, then ran it in the release mode it works perfectly. So, can't reproduce the issue. 'll check and get back to you in something pops-up in my mind.

Comment: Did you try uninstall and re-run ? And also running `flutter clean` ?

Comment: Gonna have to test some things. I'll write back later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197682/discussion-between-markus-hein-and-sukhi).

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25653. This leads to issue #[24990](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24900)

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue like yours but was able to find a way to solve it.

Instead of using `Navigator.push` use `Navigator.pushReplacement` while navigating and set up an onscreen back button to go to homescreen and navigate to homescreen using `Navigator.pushReplacement.By`.

This way, you will be able to reload the homescreen again and map loads properly.

Comment: Any Idea how to invert the transition animations when navigation back form the second to the first screen? (As now this transition is done by a pushReplacement, but the transition should look like a  pop)

Comment: You can use this package  https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition to change transition effect.