# How to pop screen without animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Basically I want to `Navigator.of(context).pop();` but without the animation.

From reading the docs I see that you can override this animations only when pushing a route. In my case, I don't know in advance if I want to show the pop animation or not when I remove the route, so I need a solution that allows me to specify if I want this animation by the time I call `pop()`

Is this possbile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874272/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-without-animation-flutter

Comment: @SharadPaghadal this does not work since depending on user input I may need to show or not show the pop animation. Overriding `buildTransitions` will predefine if the animation is played or not before pushing the route.

Answer (score 1):

To create/pop a page without animation, you can create a custom page like this.

```dart
class NoAnimationPage extends Page<dynamic> {
  const NoAnimationPage({
    LocalKey? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Route<dynamic> createRoute(BuildContext context) => PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>(
        settings: this,
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => child, 
        // don't wrap in an animation to create a page without animation.
  );
}
```

Then use `NoAnimationPage` instead of `MaterialPage` or `CupertinoPage`.

Comment: Please demonstrate how to use this with `pop`