# How to remove default navigation route animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation

I am below code which given in flutter documentation for page routing

```
// Within the `FirstRoute` widget
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
}
```

But it provides some animation while pushing and popping route.

> For Android, the entrance transition for the page slides the page
> upwards and fades it in. The exit transition is the same, but in
> reverse.
>
> The transition is adaptive to the platform and on iOS, the page slides
> in from the right and exits in reverse. The page also shifts to the
> left in parallax when another page enters to cover it. (These
> directions are flipped in environments with a right-to-left reading
> direction.)

Is there any way to route to next page without any animation?

**Edit:**
Please check the entire code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    SecondRoute.tag: (context) => SecondRoute(),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Routes",
      home: new FirstRoute(),
      routes: routes,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        if (routeSettings.name == SecondRoute.tag)
          return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, a1, a2) => SecondRoute());

        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondRoute.tag);

          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = 'second-route';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- ##### For `Navigator.push(...)`

  ```dart
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SecondRoute()),
  )
  ```
- ##### For `Navigator.pushNamed(...)`

  First, add this to your `MaterialApp`

  ```dart
  MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
      if (settings.name == '/second') 
        return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SecondRoute());

      return null;
    },
  )
  ```

  And now, you can use:

  ```dart
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
  ```

Comment: what is routeSettings here?

Comment: `routeSettings` is the parameter which needs to be passed to `onGenerateRoute`, can you tell me if the solution worked?

Comment: I checked it on Android, it's not working, it gives same animation for pushNamed.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad:  Please check my entire code. It will be helpful for you.

Comment: Your code is fine, just remove `routes: routes` from it.

Comment: it's working for me now, will accept your answer.  but can elaborate why routes attribute not required and why it causing issue?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad: Also what is the meaning of (_, a1, a2)?  as in Rémi Rousselet answer, I see  _, __, ___

Comment: marvellous! For the pushNamed option: go sure to remove the `/second` from the routes table as `onGenerateRoute` seems to be a fallback when a route cannot be found in the routes table

Answer (score 11):

The animation is performed by `MaterialPageRoute`. If you don't want it, simple use something else:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => MyRoute()),
)
```

Comment: also, I figured out   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondRoute.tag); also does the same animation, how we can avoid there?

Comment: @jitsm555 That's also done with `MaterialPageRoute` internally.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad: How we can remove the animation from there?

Comment: @jitsm555 You can do that in `MaterialApp` `onGenerateRoute`.

Comment: @jitsm555 Check out my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Flutter is now migrating to Navigator 2.0 for increased support, I would recommend checking out their [migration guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/route-transition-record-and-transition-delegate) on adding a TransitionDelegate to the Navigator. Add an instance of this class to your navigator to achieve the intended result:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class NoAnimationTransitionDelegate extends TransitionDelegate<void> {
  @override
  Iterable<RouteTransitionRecord> resolve({
    List<RouteTransitionRecord> newPageRouteHistory,
    Map<RouteTransitionRecord, RouteTransitionRecord> locationToExitingPageRoute,
    Map<RouteTransitionRecord, List<RouteTransitionRecord>> pageRouteToPagelessRoutes,
  }) {
    final List<RouteTransitionRecord> results = <RouteTransitionRecord>[];

    for (final RouteTransitionRecord pageRoute in newPageRouteHistory) {
      // Renames isEntering to isWaitingForEnteringDecision.
      if (pageRoute.isWaitingForEnteringDecision) {
        pageRoute.markForAdd();
      }
      results.add(pageRoute);

    }
    for (final RouteTransitionRecord exitingPageRoute in locationToExitingPageRoute.values) {
      // Checks the isWaitingForExitingDecision before calling the markFor methods.
      if (exitingPageRoute.isWaitingForExitingDecision) {
        exitingPageRoute.markForRemove();
        final List<RouteTransitionRecord> pagelessRoutes = pageRouteToPagelessRoutes[exitingPageRoute];
        if (pagelessRoutes != null) {
          for (final RouteTransitionRecord pagelessRoute in pagelessRoutes) {
            pagelessRoute.markForRemove();
          }
        }
      }
      results.add(exitingPageRoute);

    }
    return results;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `MyApp` with this.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{SecondRoute.tag: (context) => SecondRoute()};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Routes",
      home: new FirstRoute(),
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        if (routeSettings.name == SecondRoute.tag)
          return PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (_, a1, a2) => FadeTransition(opacity: a1 ,child: SecondRoute()),
            transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
          );

        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove it at Material Configuration level:

First, create a custom Page Transition (with no transition at all)

```dart
class _NoTransitionsBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  const _NoTransitionsBuilder();

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(
    PageRoute<T>? route,
    BuildContext? context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Widget? child,
  ) {
    return child!;
  }
}
```

Then create a PageTransitionsTheme:

```dart
PageTransitionsTheme _removeTransitions() {
  return PageTransitionsTheme(
    builders: {
      for (final platform in TargetPlatform.values)
        platform: const _NoTransitionsBuilder(),
    },
  );
}
```

Finally, add the new Transitions Theme on your `MaterialApp` constructor

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    // ...
    theme: ThemeData(
      pageTransitionsTheme: _removeTransitions(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Yasser Nascimento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76969000/1177832)'s answer is good except it naively disables animations for *all* platforms, which is likely undesirable.

To disable animations for specific platforms, define a `NoTransitionsBuilder` class like:

```dart
class NoTransitionsBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  const NoTransitionsBuilder();

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(
    PageRoute<T>? route,
    BuildContext? context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Widget? child,
  ) {
    return child!;
  }
}
```

And then in `ThemeData` configure the `pageTransitionsTheme`:

```dart
pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(
  builders: <TargetPlatform, PageTransitionsBuilder>{
    TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      TargetPlatform.linux: NoTransitionsBuilder(),
      TargetPlatform.macOS: NoTransitionsBuilder(),
      TargetPlatform.windows: NoTransitionsBuilder(),
  },
),
```

### Notes

See issue [#99052](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99052) for:

- original post of [this workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99052#issuecomment-1445252141) from [tmpfs](https://github.com/tmpfs)
- [my comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99052#issuecomment-1722595434) highlighting that a finer-grained solution for configuring animations for web (at least) is necessary

Answer (score 0):

**aidan marshal's solution is simple and works fine but there some adjustments in his code**

```
 import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class NoAnimationTransitionDelegate extends TransitionDelegate<void> {

   @override
   Iterable<RouteTransitionRecord> resolve({
       required List<RouteTransitionRecord> newPageRouteHistory,
       required Map<RouteTransitionRecord?, RouteTransitionRecord> 
       locationToExitingPageRoute, required Map<RouteTransitionRecord?, 
      List<RouteTransitionRecord>> pageRouteToPagelessRoutes}) {
    {
     final List<RouteTransitionRecord> results = <RouteTransitionRecord>[];

     for (final RouteTransitionRecord pageRoute in newPageRouteHistory) {
      // Renames isEntering to isWaitingForEnteringDecision.
      if (pageRoute.isWaitingForEnteringDecision) {
        pageRoute.markForAdd();
      }
      results.add(pageRoute);

    }
    for (final RouteTransitionRecord exitingPageRoute in locationToExitingPageRoute.values) {
      // Checks the isWaitingForExitingDecision before calling the markFor methods.
      if (exitingPageRoute.isWaitingForExitingDecision) {
        exitingPageRoute.markForRemove();
        final List<RouteTransitionRecord>? pagelessRoutes = pageRouteToPagelessRoutes[exitingPageRoute];
        if (pagelessRoutes != null) {
          for (final RouteTransitionRecord pagelessRoute in pagelessRoutes) {
            pagelessRoute.markForRemove();
          }
        }
      }
      results.add(exitingPageRoute);

    }
    return results;
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routs, here is the full code to get the permanent solution

```
      void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await ScreenUtil.ensureScreenSize();
      await ServiceLocator.setUpServiceLocator();
      initializeLoggerServer();
      serviceLocator.get<Log>().shout('App Initialized Successfully');
      runApp(AgrotopiaApp());
    }
    
    void initializeLoggerServer() {
      Logger.root.level = Level.ALL; // defaults to Level.INFO
      Logger.root.onRecord.listen((record) {
        debugPrint('${record.level.name}: ${record.time}: ${record.message}');
      });
    }
      //create this class to make no animation 
    class NoAnimationPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
      NoAnimationPageRoute({required WidgetBuilder builder, required RouteSettings settings})
          : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);
    
      @override
      Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(opacity: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1.0), child: child);
      }
    }
    
   
    class FadePageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
      FadePageRoute({required WidgetBuilder builder, required RouteSettings settings})
          : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);
    
      @override
      Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
      }
    }
    
    
    class AgrotopiaApp extends StatelessWidget {
      AgrotopiaApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ScreenUtilInit(
            designSize: context.resources.variables.screenDesignSize,
            splitScreenMode: false,
            minTextAdapt: true,
            useInheritedMediaQuery: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
              return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => LoaderModelView(), lazy: true),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => GlobalAppProvider(), lazy: true),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => OnBoardingViewModel(), lazy: true),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => BottomNavViewModel(), lazy: true),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => PlaceOrderViewModel(), lazy: true),
                  ChangeNotifierProvider(
                      create: (_) => PaymentViewModel(), lazy: true),
                ],
                child: MaterialApp(
                    navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
                    title: context.resources.variables.appName,
                    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                    theme: context.resources.styles.appTheme(),
                    home: const SplashScreen(),
                    // home: CollectUserData(),
                    // home: const UserOnBoardingPage(),
                    initialRoute: '/',
                     onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                      
            switch (settings.name) {
              
              case '/home':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage(), settings: settings);
              case '/app':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => AgrotopiaApp(), settings: settings);
              case '/settingpage':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => SettingPage(), settings: settings);
              case '/placeordermenu':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => PlaceOrderMenu(), settings: settings);
              case '/placeorderpage':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => PlaceOrderPage(), settings: settings);
              case '/paymentinformationpage':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => PaymentInformationPage(), settings: settings);
              case '/orderstatuspage':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrderStatusPage(), settings: settings);
              case '/orderdetailspage':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrderDetailsPage(), settings: settings);
              case '/confirmation':
                return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => Confirmation(), settings: settings);
              // case '/orderdetailspage':
              //   return NoAnimationPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrderDetailsPage(), settings: settings);
              default:
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Scaffold());
            }
          },
                    
            
                    ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
```

now do navigate to another page

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/orderstatuspage');
```