# Navigator.push without animation - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several register forms with next buttons and I would like to switch between the different screens with

```
onTap: () => { Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SomeOtherScaffold()))
  },
```

but without the default animation that comes with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196913/how-to-change-navigation-animation-using-flutter

Comment: Duplicate of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874272/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-without-animation-flutter

Comment: see this   https://stackoverflow.com/a/75578904/17331686

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use other animation, you can use `transitionBuilder`, in your `PageRoute`. How you can use this represented for you below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Page1(),
  ));
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Go!'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return child;
    },
  );
}
```

And if you want to transition instantly, you can do this:

```
transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0)
```

This will decrease down the transition time to 0 second, which will eventually results to quick transition speed.

To know more about `Page Animation Transition` follow these articles:

1. [Page Route Animation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation)
2. [Everything you need for Flutter Page Transition](https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823)

You need to define something for your transition, if you don't want the default one, and this answer will help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In MaterialApp

```
     theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
              builders: {
                TargetPlatform.android :  _NoAnimationTransition(),
                TargetPlatform.iOS :  _NoAnimationTransition(),
               // if you have more you can add them here
              }
            )
          ),
```

create a `PageTransitionsBuilder`

```
class _NoAnimationTransition extends PageTransitionsBuilder{
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(_, __, ___, ____, Widget child) => child;
}
```

All navigation animations will be removed