# Flutter Web - remove default page transition on named routes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm looking to update the default page transition to remove the left to right page transition that occurs by default and instead have zero transition. I've seen supporting documentation that allows creating a PageRouteBuilder and setting a duration of zero seconds, but I'm unsure how I can do this for named routes.

For example, I'd like to be able to call and have zero transition:

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');`

How can I change the default so that all page transitions have zero transition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove default navigation route animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773077/how-to-remove-default-navigation-route-animation)

Comment: @OMiShah Would I have to declare the onGenerateRoute for every single named route? Is there a way to do this as a default?

Comment: recent beta flutter took out page transitions for both Web and Desktop and its by API design according to Flutter team

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set the navigation theme in the root `MaterialApp`. You can pass the navigation animation to each platform you are targeting as shown below.

```dart
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
          builders: {
            TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But `TargetPlatform` is not available for web, in fact it gets not the target platform but the OS the app is running on.

As a work around for this, you can use `kIsWeb` Boolean from flutter foundation package, another thing you need a custom `PageTransitionsBuilder` that has no animations.

custom `PageTransitionsBuilder`

```dart
class NoTransitionsBuilder extends PageTransitionsBuilder {
  const NoTransitionsBuilder();

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions<T>(
    PageRoute<T>? route,
    BuildContext? context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    Widget? child,
  ) {
    // only return the child without warping it with animations
    return child!;
  }
}
```

Finally the `pageTransitionsTheme`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;


        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
          builders: kIsWeb
              ? {
                  // No animations for every OS if the app running on the web
                  for (final platform in TargetPlatform.values)
                    platform:const NoTransitionsBuilder(),
                }
              : const {
                // handel other platforms you are targeting
              },
        ),
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!! Super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `MaterialApp` widget has a `pageTransitionsTheme` field where you can map  specific `PageTransitionBuilder`s to a specific platform. you can read more about PageTransitionsTheme [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PageTransitionsTheme-class.html)

Comment: How would I set it to have no transition?

Answer (score 0):

Seek for
1.duration inside animation and set it to zero ,or
2.put animation as Animation.none
This might help you.