# Flutter BaseScreen keeps rebuilding / Not wanted rebuilds

Tags: flutter

I have [a simple app](https://github.com/dleurs/flutter_bottom_nav_bar_on_base_screen), with 3 bottom nav items.
However, when I click on one of the bottom nav items bellow, the entire page is moving, from right to left with iOS, from bottom with android.
I want my bottom navigation app to stay at the same place, as [traditionnal Bottom Nav Bar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

[image]

I know  [I can find](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)  working implementations of bottom navigation bar using a `StatefulWidget`, a `int _selectedIndex = 0;` and a `static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions`,

**but my app is already big and using a different mecanism in 3 steps defines below :** (that you find on my [github repo](https://github.com/dleurs/flutter_bottom_nav_bar_on_base_screen)) :

#### 1. MaterialApp defines _onGenerateRoute :

main.dart

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Keep bottom navigation',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
    );
```

main.dart

```
  Route<dynamic> _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.computer:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ComputerScreen());
      case AppRoutes.phone:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhoneScreen());
      case AppRoutes.person:
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonScreen());
    }
  }
```

route_config.dart

```
class AppRoutes {
  static const String computer = '/computer';
  static const String phone = '/phone';
  static const String person = '/person';
}
```

#### 2. Every screens extends BaseScreen as a State :

screens/computer_screen.dart

```
class ComputerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ComputerScreenState createState() => _ComputerScreenState();
}

class _ComputerScreenState extends BaseScreenState<ComputerScreen> {
  @override
  String get currentRoute => AppRoutes.computer;

  @override
  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child:
          Text("Computer screen", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 3. Base Sceen defines the basics of a screen :

base_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keep_bottomnav/bottom_nav_bar.dart';

abstract class BaseScreenState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  String get currentRoute;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: this.buildAppBar(context),
      body: this.buildScreen(context),
      bottomNavigationBar: this.buildBottomNavigationBar(context),
      floatingActionButton: this.buildFloatingActionButton(context),
    );
  }

  Widget buildScreen(BuildContext context);

  PreferredSizeWidget buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }

  Widget buildBottomNavigationBar(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavBar(
      selectedRoute: currentRoute,
      onSelectRoute: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }

  Widget buildFloatingActionButton(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }

  bool get centerFloatingActionButton => false;

  void _onItemTapped(String route) {
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, route, (route) => false);
  }
}
```

#### 4. UI of BottomNavBar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keep_bottomnav/bottom_nav_bar_item.dart';
import 'package:keep_bottomnav/route_config.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedRoute;
  final ValueChanged<String> onSelectRoute;

  BottomNavBar({this.selectedRoute, this.onSelectRoute});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double itemWidth = (screenWidth / 3);
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 65,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildNavigationItem(
                AppRoutes.computer,
                icon: Icon(Icons.computer),
                title: "Computer 1",
                itemWidth: itemWidth,
              ),
              _buildNavigationItem(
                AppRoutes.phone,
                icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
                title: "Phone 2",
                itemWidth: itemWidth,
              ),
              _buildNavigationItem(
                AppRoutes.person,
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                title: "Person 3",
                itemWidth: itemWidth,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNavigationItem(String route,
      {Widget icon, String title, itemWidth}) {
    return BottomNavBarItem(
      isSelected: selectedRoute == route,
      icon: icon,
      title: title,
      minWidth: itemWidth,
      onTap: () {
        if (onSelectRoute != null) {
          onSelectRoute(route);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomNavBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final Widget icon;
  final String title;
  final double minWidth;

  BottomNavBarItem(
      {Key key,
      @required this.icon,
      @required this.title,
      this.isSelected = false,
      this.onTap,
      this.minWidth = 50})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: this.onTap,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                      color: isSelected ? Colors.yellow : Colors.transparent,
                      width: 3.0))),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              icon,
              Text(
                title.toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 9.0),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Using [Hero](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) on BottomNavItems was buggy

Comment: The reason it comes from left/bottom is because you are using Navigation

Comment: @quoci is there a way to fake the behavior of bottomnavbar with Navigation ?

Comment: If you don't want the animation you could see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874272/how-to-navigate-to-other-page-without-animation-flutter)

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is coming from `MaterialPageRoute`. When navigating to and from a `Widget`, you need to supply a `PageRoute`. The `PageRoute` is the one responsible for telling the framework how to transition from one screen to another. By using `MaterialPageRoute`, you are using its predefined values where it adds the animation you see above. To remove that `animation`, you can create your own `PageRoute` with no animation:

```
Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => MyPage(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return child;
    },
  );
}
```

Use `_createRoute()` in your Navigator instead of `MaterialPageRoute`:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
```

How the Problem was fixed :

```
  Route<dynamic> _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.computer:
        return _createRoute(ComputerScreen());
      case AppRoutes.phone:
        return _createRoute(PhoneScreen());
      case AppRoutes.person:
      default:
        return _createRoute(PersonScreen());
    }
  }
}

Route _createRoute(Widget screen) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => screen,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return child;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped @DimitriLeurs