# Create an instant transition to page in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have these two stateful widget Page1 and Page2.
I'm trying to make the second page appear on the first one as soon as the transition is triggered and without any scroll, fade or any effects. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Replace initial Route in MaterialApp without animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation/43685697#43685697)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyCustomRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  MyCustomRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
      return child;
    // Fades between routes. (If you don't want any animation, 
    // just return child.)
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation example',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/': return new MyCustomRoute(
            builder: (_) => new MyHomePage(),
            settings: settings,
          );
          case '/somewhere': return new MyCustomRoute(
            builder: (_) => new Somewhere(),
            settings: settings,
          );
        }
        assert(false);
      }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Navigation example'),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new Container(
                  child: const Text('This is a header'),
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              title: const Text('Navigate somewhere'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/somewhere');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          'This is a home page.',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Somewhere extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          'Congrats, you did it.',
        ),
      ),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Somewhere'),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new DrawerHeader(
              child: new Container(
                child: const Text('This is a header'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```