# Is there a way to exclude a BottomAppBar from animations in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, bottomappbar

I tried to wrap it in a Hero widget, as that should achieve what I want. This works with BottomNavigationBar, but not with BottomAppBar, which gives this error: `Scaffold.geometryOf() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.` I tried to give it a context by using Builder, but that did not work either. Here is a sample app to showcase the behaviour:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: PageOne(),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _bottomNavigationBar() {
  return BottomNavigationBar(items: [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), title: Text('menu')),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), title: Text('back')),
  ]);
}

Widget _bottomAppBar() {
  return BottomAppBar(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: null),
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: null),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Hero(
        tag: 'bottomNavigationBar',
        child: _bottomAppBar(),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 200,
          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Hero(
        tag: 'bottomNavigationBar',
        child: _bottomAppBar(),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 200,
          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_one),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the animation that is used with the Navigation stack. Therefore, getting rid of the animation during the page load will stop this animation. I added the PageRouteBuilder to the PageOne class in your example to get rid of the Navigation stack animation. Use the code below to replace the PageOne class from your example.

```
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomAppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 200,
          icon: Icon(Icons.looks_two),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            PageRouteBuilder(
              pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => PageTwo(),
              transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) =>
                  Container(child: child),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are additional ways to control the animation for Navigation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680902/replace-initial-route-in-materialapp-without-animation)
(Oh, and I got rid of the Hero() widget)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by wrapping the Row with a Hero widget in BottomAppBar. This still allows page transitions, and does not animate the BottomAppBar as intended.

```
BottomAppBar(
  child: Hero(
    tag: 'bottomAppBar',
    child: Material(
      child: Row(
        ...
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

However, this has laggy animations when using a CircularNotchedRectangle.